# Como calcular 'horário de término' em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
qpd = int(input('Quantidade produzida: '))  # qpd = Quantidade Produzida
qpg = int(input('Quantidade programada: '))  # qpg = Quantidade Programada
qrs = qpg - qpd  # qrs = Quantidade Restante
qpc = qrs / 550  # qpc = Quantidade por Carro
mrs = int(qpc * 18)  # mrs = Minutos Restantes
if mrs > 60:
    hora = mrs // 60  # hora = Horas até o término da solução
    minuto = mrs % 60  # minuto = Minuto até o término da solução
    print(f'Faltam, aproximadamente, {hora} horas e {minuto} minutos para'
          ' o término da solução.')
else:
    print(f'Faltam, aproximadamente, {mrs} minutos para'
          ' o término da solução.')
```

Sou iniciante em Python e estou criando um código que calcula o horário do término de um processo. O código ainda é bem simples porque meu conhecimento ainda é muito limitado.

Quero que meu código calcule que horas o processo vai ser finalizado, mas ainda não sei como. Por enquanto, só sei calcular quantas horas e minutos faltam para o fim do processo. Fiz algumas pesquisas e achei o módulo `datetime`, mas não consegui informações que me ajudassem com esse problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, bem vindo!

A biblioteca `datetime` é realmente uma boa solução para trabalhar com datas e horários. Por exemplo, na forma abaixo podemos definir a data e horário atuais:

```
import datetime as dt

print(dt.datetime.now())
```

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 3, 21, 1, 529738)
```

No resultado acima temos a função `now()` que retorna a hora atual numa estrutura própria `datetime` armazenando, respectivamente, o ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto, segundo e microssegundo.

Outra função interessante dessa biblioteca é a facilidade de efetuar operações com horários utilizando `dt.timedelta()`. Exemplo:

```
agora = dt.datetime.now();
daqui_um_segundo = agora + dt.timedelta(seconds = 1);
daqui_um_minuto = agora + dt.timedelta(minutes = 1);
daqui_uma_hora = agora + dt.timedelta(hours = 1);
```

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 3, 27, 29, 524590)
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 3, 27, 30, 524590)
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 3, 28, 29, 524590)
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 4, 27, 29, 524590)
```

Para melhor visualização é possível utilizar a função `strftime` para formatar a exibição do horário:

```
agora1 = agora.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
agora2 = agora.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
agora3 = agora.strftime("%H:%M")

print(agora1)
print(agora2)
print(agora3)
```

```
2018-09-15 03:27:29
03:27:29
03:27
```

Veja que a função `strftime` recebe um parâmetro que determina o formato da data e hora desejados, onde cada letra corresponde à algum elemento. `%H` é hora, `%Y` é ano e assim por diante. Os outros caracteres fora os identificadores são opcionais.

Sabendo dessas informações é possível estabelecer o horário futuro baseado em um intervalo de tempo. No seu caso você tem os minutos e as horas para o processo. Somente os minutos já é o suficiente utilizando os recursos citados. Veja:

```
qpd = int(input('Quantidade produzida: '))  # qpd = Quantidade Produzida
qpg = int(input('Quantidade programada: '))  # qpg = Quantidade Programada
qrs = qpg - qpd  # qrs = Quantidade Restante
qpc = qrs / 550  # qpc = Quantidade por Carro
mrs = int(qpc * 18)  # mrs = Minutos Restantes
if mrs > 60:
    hora = mrs // 60  # hora = Horas até o término da solução
    minuto = mrs % 60  # minuto = Minuto até o término da solução
    print(f'Faltam, aproximadamente, {hora} horas e {minuto} minutos para'
          ' o término da solução.')
else:
    print(f'Faltam, aproximadamente, {mrs} minutos para'
          ' o término da solução.')

hora_atual = dt.datetime.now()
hora_final = hora_atual + dt.timedelta(minutes = mrs)

hora_atual = hora_atual.strftime("%H:%M")
hora_final = hora_final.strftime("%H:%M")
print(f"A hora atual é {hora_atual}")
print(f"O horário final do processo é {hora_final}")
```

```
Quantidade produzida: 45
Quantidade programada: 567
Faltam, aproximadamente, 17 minutos para o término da solução.
A hora atual é 03:45
O horário final do processo é 04:02
```

Comment: Lorran, quase 1 ano e meio depois eu volto pra te agradecer. Desculpa por ter demorado tanto tempo. Sua resposta me ajudou MUITO por ter sido simples e fácil de entender. Obrigado pelo seu tempo e disposição. E de novo, me perdoe a demora pra agradecer. Que Deus te abençoe!

Comment: Eduardo, o importante foi a minha respostar ser útil para você! Qualquer dúvida é só postar aqui!